# Update current page URL but maintain the back button state

Tags: javascript, url

**CONTEXT**: I have an app that displays a list of products. When clicking on a product you are taken to a new page which displays more information about that product including available colors.

When clicking on a color the associated product image is displayed. The url hash is also updated with the color info so when reloading the page the specific color image will be shown.

**PROBLEM**: When user clicks a bunch of colors and then tries to go back to the product list page using the back button, the url is updated based on the state changes made when clicking colors. I would like to update my code so that when the user clicks the back button they are sent back to the list of products.

Essentially I want to update the url hash and maintaining the original state of the back button.

This is the code I use to update my url:

```
window.location.hash = color_parameter
```

Is the intended functionality achievable without using `window.history` / history.js? If so, how? If not, what do I need to implement to make this work and still be cross browser friendly?

I would prefer to NOT add a back button into the html pointing to `document.referrer`

Comment: You might try a solution like [this](http://dev.enekoalonso.com/2008/12/29/modifying-the-url-hash-without-affecting-the-browser-history/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471008/location-hash-and-back-history).  Personally, I think it would make a lot of sense to have something like "back to product list" on the product page.

Comment: @mellamokb - `window.location.replace(window.location.href.split('#')[0] + '#' + parameter_string)` is what I was looking for. I guess this question is a duplicate although I did not come across http://stackoverflow.com/a/11471401/802521 in the hour I was google'ing.

Comment: @mellamokb - if you add your comment as an answer Ill accept it as this question's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now that I know there is such a thing as [window.location.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471008/location-hash-and-back-history) maybe this is not the best solution anymore, but its still a solution:

A solution: stop putting the colors in the address itself. Just have the colors dynamically change on the page. Maybe send an Ajax request to save the most recent color on the server session in case the user refreshes the page. Then on page refresh, the PHP page (or ASP or whatever you use) will print the most recent color into your JS variable, and the same color will be shown without the address being changed and without the back button being broken.

Comment: thanks for the input but I need the colors in the url. There are actually a number of other variables (gender, orientation,etc) that are also plugged into the url. This allows users to share a link and that link being able to reproduce exactly what the 'sharer' is seeing on their screen.