# What exactly happens when user clicks on back button in browser?

Tags: browser, cross-browser

Someone please explain what will happen in browser when we click on its back button? Like what event will be fired? What will happen to DOM elements?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods of using the back button, the back button changes the state of the webpages and can be taken advantage of in many ways. A few examples below.

[Hash History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471008/location-hash-and-back-history)

[HTML5 PushState](https://zinoui.com/blog/single-page-apps-html5-pushstate)

[Popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate)

Hope these help