# History back in overflowed div using Tocify

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tocify inserts named divs above headers. It uses hash tags to navigate and pushes to history. We use Tocify to target overflowed div content area--it works great.

The back button updates hash and triggers event, but scroll does not execute--no errors. Same logic with hash in window load event works as expected.

What am I missing?

```
function scrollToAnchor(hash) {
  alert("Scroll to: " + hash);
  var dTag = $("div[name='" + hash + "']");
  $('.topic').animate({ scrollTop: dTag.offset().top }, 'slow');
}


  $(window).load(function () {
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
    if (hash != '') {
      scrollToAnchor(hash);
    }
  });

  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    $(window).on('popstate', function () {
      var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
      if (hash != '') {
        scrollToAnchor(hash);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your code only sort of works if topic has its own scrollbar. To scrollTop inside an element:

```js
var loaded = $.Deferred();

$(window).ready(function() {
  var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
  if (hash != '') {
    scrollToAnchor(hash);
  }

  var offsets = [];
  var item = function(key, value) {
    return {
      key: key,
      value: value
    };
  };
  offsets.push(new item('topic', $(".topic").offset().top));

  $(".topic div").each(function(index, element) {
    offsets.push(new item(element.getAttribute("name"), element.offsetTop));
  });

  loaded.resolve(offsets);
});

function scrollToAnchor(hash) {
  var dTag = $("div[name='" + hash + "']");

  // makes sure on window ready as ran
  loaded.done(function(offsets) {
    var grep = function(item) {
      return $.grep(offsets, function(_item) {
        return _item.key == item;
      })[0].value;
    };

    $(".topic").animate({
      scrollTop: grep(hash) - grep("topic")
    }, 'slow');
  });
}

if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
    if (hash != '') {
      scrollToAnchor(hash);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.topic {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#1">1</a>
<a href="#2">2</a>
<a href="#3">3</a>
<br>
<div class="topic">

  <div name="1">
    1
  </div>
  <div name="2">
    2
  </div>
  <div name="3">
    3
  </div>

</div>
```

> If you didn't want topic to have a scrollbar

Just change

```
function scrollToAnchor(hash) {
  alert("Scroll to: " + hash);
  var dTag = $("div[name='" + hash + "']");
  $('.topic').animate({ scrollTop: dTag.offset().top }, 'slow');
}
```

to

```
function scrollToAnchor(hash) {
  alert("Scroll to: " + hash);
  var dTag = $("div[name='" + hash + "']");
  $('window, body').animate({ scrollTop: dTag.offset().top }, 'slow');
}
```

**UPDATE**

I am not sure the Deferred was really needed in the first version. I think this simpler version may also work fine. [jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/wmobk908/)

Comment: If the above doesn't work. My best guess is that one or more of your selectors are wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The scrollToAnchor works on load, however does not work when hash updated via back button.  Here is link to sample page where you will see it scrolls on load, however does not scroll with back button update of url hashtag: https://woundreference.com/app/topic?id=35#introduction

Comment: The main issue on that page in that the anchor tag don't have href attributes so scrollToAnchor will never be called. Based on how you're issue the code. You'd also need and on click handler. To modify the default a tag click behavior.

Comment: mmm...I looked at it again I am not sure why onload isn't scrolling. Also modifying the hash is tracking. I suggest these resources https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471008/location-hash-and-back-history and http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Comment: Thanks again Nick.  Seems the main problem was that I referenced the wrong nested div (should have used #topic-text rather than .topic.